# SharePoint migration tool permission

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepointmigrationtool

I am using SharePoint migration tool to copy content (libraries , Site Pages) from source SPO site to destination SPO site. I have gone through the docs and an account with Site Collection administrator access to the target SharePoint site needs to be used. However the account being used for the source site should also be the site collection admin. Is there any specific reason to have site collection admin rights associated with source site as well ? Microsoft did not mention the site collection admin rights with source site as well. Am i missing something ?

This is kind of urgent and quick response will be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Tayyab

Answer (score 1):

Though it might not have the specific requirement for source site in written, it gives the requirement in the migration tool itself (which you might have seen already).

[image]

I think the tool is designed that way to avoid potential permission issues when accessing the resource, since site collection administrators have access to all contents regardless of unique permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The minimum permission allowed is the site collection admin. There's also a requirement of being global/SP admin as well to migrate at an org level.

It's mentioned actually in this document: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/how-to-use-the-sharepoint-migration-tool

Comment: To migrate content at org level:

How can one user from another org, (from where source content) be a global admin to destination org?

I tried to give SC admin permissions to guest user and it worked, but how do I make the guest user the Global admin?